# Форматирование YAML с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, словари, yaml

Не могу правильно отформатировать файл для записи его в формате YAML. Требуется писать файл такого вида:

```
---
dnaSize: 177
primer: GTACACTACATGTCCATAGCAGGCTTG
primerOffset: 15
stages:
- reducedNucleotide: "T"
  delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  ...
- reducedNucleotide: "A"
  delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  ...
```

Однако получается файл такого формата:

```
!!set
'---': null
dnaSize: 177
primer: GTACACTACATGTCCATAGCAGGCTTG
primerOffset: 15
stages:
  'reducedNucleotide: "T"':
   delays: &id001
   - 1
   - 5
   - 350
   ...
  'reducedNucleotide: "A"':
   delays: &id001
   - 1
   - 5
   - 350
   ...
```

Запись в файл производиться следующим образом:

```
arr = {'---'}
to_yaml = {
           'dnaSize': 177,
           'primer': 'GTACACTACATGTCCATAGCAGGCTTG',
           'primerOffset': 15,
           'stages': {
                      'reducedNucleotide: "T"': {
                                                 'delays': delays
                                                 },
                      'reducedNucleotide: "A"': {
                                                 'delays': delays
                                                 },
                      'reducedNucleotide: "C"': {
                                                 'delays': delays
                                                 },
                      'reducedNucleotide: "G"': {
                                                 'delays': delays
                                                 }
                      }
           }

with open('/home/gamma-dna/Experiments/data.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(arr, outfile)
    yaml.dump(to_yaml, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

где delays - список из int. Просмотрев пару мануалов так и не понял как записать в начало `---` без кавычек и как записать строчки `reducedNucleotide: "T"` как надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
to_yaml = {
           'dnaSize': 177,
           'primer': 'GTACACTACATGTCCATAGCAGGCTTG',
           'primerOffset': 15,
           'stages': [{'reducedNucleotide': "T", 'delays': delays},
                      {'reducedNucleotide': "A", 'delays': delays},
                      {'reducedNucleotide': "C", 'delays': delays},
                      {'reducedNucleotide': "G", 'delays': delays}]
}

class NoAliasDumper(yaml.Dumper):
    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True

data = "---\n{}".format(yaml.dump(to_yaml, Dumper=NoAliasDumper))

with open('/home/gamma-dna/Experiments/data.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(data)
```

результат:

```
In [32]: print(data)
---
dnaSize: 177
primer: GTACACTACATGTCCATAGCAGGCTTG
primerOffset: 15
stages:
- delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  reducedNucleotide: T
- delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  reducedNucleotide: A
- delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  reducedNucleotide: C
- delays:
  - 1
  - 5
  - 350
  reducedNucleotide: G
```

Comment: Спасибо работает. А как быть с 'reducedNucleotide: "A"' не подскажете? Должно быть                     - reducedNucleotide: "A": и дальше delays но без указателя.

Comment: @Дмитрий, для этого нужно по другому формировать словарь `to_yaml` - смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: а от указателей никак не избавиться? просто этот файл потом кушает другая программа, и она очень чувствительна к формату. Просто когда вставляю в первом уровне словаря, как например to_yaml = {'data': delays}, никаких указателей нет, просто выводятся данные

Comment: @Дмитрий, уже избавился... ;)

Comment: всё, вижу, спасибо